# Kernel shutting down with no error message in Linux while it does not happen in Windows

Tags: differential-equations, linux

When I run the code to solve ordinary differential equations using NDSolve, the code is stopped with no error message in Linux while it does not happen in Window.

Specifically, the code solves the ordinary differential equations with the randomly chosen parameter values. Then, after solving the equations, the code again solves the equations with the parameter values which are again randomly selected. The code repeats the above procedure. During the procedure, the code is suddenly stopped without error message in Linux while the code does not in Window.

Note that depending on the parameters, the ordinary differential equations could include the stiff function.

I have no idea why this happens. Please help me... Below is a part of the code, which shows the ordinary differential equation. The "deg" function could be stiff depending on the randomly chosen parameters (i.e. mag1, mag2, interval, smooth and rotate).

```
crotate = Mod[crotate, 24];

days = 10;

mag1 = cmag1;
mag2 = cmag2;
interval = cinterval;
smooth = csmooth;
rotate = crotate;

deg[t_] := 
  mag1*0.5*((1 + Tanh[(t - 24*Floor[t/24])/smooth]) - (1 + 
        Tanh[(t - 24*Floor[t/24] - interval)/smooth]) + (1 + 
        Tanh[(t - 24*Floor[t/24] - 24)/smooth])) + mag2;
degf[t_] := deg[t - rotate];

afive = {elf3v};

atwo = {elf3v[0] == 0.5};

aone = {

   elf3v'[t] == m51[t] - degf[t]*elf3v[t]

   };

qtt = NDSolve[Join[aone, atwo], afive, {t, 0, 24*days}, 
   MaxSteps -> 10000000];

ZZ1 = Table[elf3v[t] /. qtt[[1]], {t, (days - 1)*24, days*24, 0.02}];
```

[image]

Comment: If you show us your equations, someone might be able to help you

Comment: I added the part of my code, which shows the ordinary differential equation.

Comment: I do not think anyone will want to type your equation which is very had to read. Why not just copy the actual code into your question? Then we can copy and paste it.

Comment: Thanks for the nice comment. I copied the actual code in my question.